# Angular, guard for base route not working

Tags: javascript, angular

First time when entering *http://localhost:4200* `BaseLanguageGuard` is triggered, but then if I navigate to another route and then click `routerLink` which navigates me back to *http://localhost:4200*, `BaseLanguageGuard` doesn't get called anymore.

What am I doing wrong and how to trigger guard when navigate to base (I mean *http://localhost:4200*) url?

***Routes:***

```
const appRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [BaseLanguageGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: ':lang',
        canActivateChild: [FeatureLanguageGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('./features/mainstream/mainstream.module').then(
                (m) => m.MainstreamModule
              ),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a redirect path to a component and add your `canActivate` guard there. So whenever you reached at `localhost:4200`, the redirect path will be called and your `home-component/default-component` will be loaded and `canActivate` guard will be functional.

Comment: @Kirubel Home-component url is not static, it's depend on the language, for example if you have chosen English your home url will be localhost:4200/en, if you have chosen Russian your home url will be localhost:4200/ru, because of that I can't provide a redirect path.

Comment: I understand, but still as far as I know, there should be one default component for route guards to work properly. If you've saved those chosen languages of user in local storage or be it session, then you can extract the language and navigate by default.

Comment: What does your `routerLink` look like?